# How to display streams from a signal server WEBRTCSINK with GstWebRTC API in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webrtc, gstreamer, rtsp

I use the [gst-plugins-rs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/tree/main/net/webrtc/) repository to convert RTSP streams into WEBRTC using gstreamer. I have a Vue.js application where I need to display streams on a page.

My problem is that I can't find out how to get the stream data that is on the signal server, also I don't know how the API works because there is no Swagger documentation

Please tell me what url the stream can be located at and how to display it on the page. What Vue libraries are there that will help me?

Before that, I used this player https://github.com/vdalex25/WebRtcPlayer together with the backend https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC and everything worked, but it was decided to change the backend and use gst-plugins-rs instead, Now I can’t find information on how to display streams

Also I tried to display streams on the page using the vue-webrtc library